# String preparation when calling stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Actually, I have code that uses Entity Framework 4.1 in Visual Studio 2010. Everything is working fine except for one thing : it doesn't seem to "prepare" the parameters like a good old `[parameters.Add]` habitually did.

Here's my code :

```
using (MyEnterprisesEntities dataContext = new 
                             MyEnterprisesEntities(entityBuilder.ToString()))
{
         dataContext.CompanyInitializer(connection.Catalog,
                                        args.CompanyId,
                                        args.CompanyName);
}
```

So, if my company's name is `O'Brian and sons` (actually it passed before through a WCF web service so it's more in this form: `O\'Brian and sons`), it's seem to break my stored procedure (including the possibility of allowing SQL injection).

Is there a way to avoid this situation with EDMX or the old way is more reliable ?

Comment: How do you actually invoke the stored procedure? Have you tried passing SqlParameter objects instead of using strings?

Comment: None of these methods.

The stored procedure is added in Edmx and configured via the Model Browser into Stored Procedure. A complex Type is generated and the stored procedure is inserted into the Function Imports. It's then executed directly in the code and the parameters are feeded with the informations I received from my Web Service.

Comment: To be more clear, I'm just wondering if the entity framework, when it builds its call to the Stored Procedure, takes care of the string preparation before passing it to the stored procedure.

Comment: This is suppose to pass parameters by default. Just use the "Add function import" of EDMX model to add function for your stored proc. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't not need to do anything prior to the call to your Stored Proc.
To help you, start the SQL Profiler to see what are the parameters sent to your database.
I ran some tests and if I'm using a parameter like O'Brian, the framework automatically double the quote in the query to SQL.

Comment: The SQL Profiler helped me to find that actually, there was another problem that, in the end, causes all that crappy problem. Thanks for the hint.